# Why does the "which" system command give a 256 code with os.system in python?

Tags: python, macos, os.system

I am on mac OSX.

I have a program where I am trying to call downloaded libraries from the terminal. This is not possible if I don't know where the libraries are. I will use pip as a common library example

```
>>> os.system("pip -h")
32512
>>> os.system("which pip")
256
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014222/what-are-response-codes-for-256-and-512-for-os-system-in-python-scripting) response to the 256 error, however, I still don't understand why it appears here. It says it is "frequently used to indicate an argument parsing failure" however the exact command works because this does not seem to be an argument parsing error to me.

I would like to be able to do something to the effect of:

```
os.system(os.system("which pip") +" -h")
```

If there is another way of doing this, I would love to hear it

Comment: 256 means that `which` exited with status code 1, which means that the `pip` command could not be found. 32512 means that `pip -h` exited with status code 127, which is what the shell exits with when the command can't be found. TL;DR you don't have `pip` in your PATH.

Comment: Use [os.waitstatus_to_exitcode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitstatus_to_exitcode) to get the exitcode from the returned wait status: `os.waitstatus_to_exitcode(256) == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `os.system` like that (and don't use `which`, either). Try this to find a program:

```
import os

for bin_dir in os.environ.get("PATH").split(":"):
  if 'my_program' in os.listdir(bin_dir):
    executable_path = os.path.join(bin_dir, 'my_program')
    break
```

Note that this does assume that `PATH` was properly set by whatever process started the script. If you are running it from a shell, that shouldn't be an issue.

In general, using `os.system` to call common *NIX utilities and trying to parse the results is unidiomatic-- it's writing python as if it was a shell script.

Then, instead of using `system` to run `pip`, use the solution describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51704613/6689725).